# How to aggregate 2D and 3D documents in Forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to aggregate 2D sheets and 3D models together. I found a new class named `AggregatedView`
from links below:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7
- https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/992b1a26606003e7e4efd9c550fb5b9f
- https://gist.github.com/yiskang/c404af571ba4d631b5929c777503891e

I tried to apply `AggregatedView` in my project. I successfully aggregated the 3D models, however, when I aggregated 2D sheets and a 3D model, it seemed that 2D and 3D documents are in different coordination. But the gif video in first link shows 2D and 3D are merged well. Did I miss some config setting?

[How I did in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBDns.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `AggregatedView` class isn't able - at least not in all cases - to properly sync the scale of the 2D drawings and 3D models. In that case you may need to aggregate the designs and set their scales manually. This blog post explains how you can specify the "placement transform" for newly loaded models: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.